# Can not load pickled custom class in different directory, what is happening? How do I import the class needed?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, pickle

I'm trying to load a pickled custom class in a different directory and I am having two errors.

The file structure is as follows

```
/project
|
|--/data
|
|--/src
|  
|  |--__init__.py
|
|  |--/calculate
|     |--__init__.py
|     |--run_calc.py
|     |--calc_class.py
|
|  |--/plot
|     |--__init__.py
|     |--run_plotter
```

In the **run_calc.py**, I calculate things and pickle it using by importing the custom class as follow

```
import pickle
from cust_class import animal

instance_animal = animal(specie, age)

with open('../../data/picked_class.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(instance_animal, f)
```

The **cust_class.py** is like this

```
class animal:
    def__init__(self, specie, age)
    self.specie = specie
    self.age = age
```

Now when I try to load the pickle in the run_plotter in a different directory as shown above, I get the following error.

**run_plotter.py**

```
with open('../../data/pickled_class.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    loaded = pickle.load(f)
```

**console output**

```
$python run_plotter.py
ImportError: No module named cust_class
```

Now, if I copy and paste the calc_class.py into the /plot directory next to run_plotter.py, the pickle.load works. But, if I try to import the calc_class.py inside **run_plotter.py** as shown below

```
from ..parser import bsig_class
```

**gives me error**

```
$python run_plotter.py
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

The two question is, does pickle need to have a class imported to have classes loaded in a different directory? How do I import this class so pickle file can be loaded in a different directory?